# open method is not being called in Flink RichMapFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to use apache flink for a simple example described at [Shortcuts](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/checkpoint/CheckpointedFunction.html). However, I noticed the open method is never called and as a result I get null pointer exception on first line of map function.

```
public class MyMap extends RichMapFunction<Integer, Integer> {

    private ValueState<Integer> test;

    public void open(Configuration cfg) {
        test = getRuntimeContext().getState(new 
                ValueStateDescriptor<Integer>("myTest", Integer.class));
        System.out.println("1:" + test);
    }


    @Override
    public Integer map(Integer i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("2:" + test.value()); //test is null here
        test.update(test.value() == null? 1: test.value() + 1);
        System.out.println("3:" + test.value());
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Did you try to @Override the open function?

<s>`test`</s> `test.value` is supposed to be `null` the first time. 
You are on keyed context, which means that each message has a key which flink already knows about. When you enter a stateful operator, flink will try to fetch a value for that key from the configured state backend. Unless you configure the `ValueStateDescriptor` to have a default (it is deprecated), the first time you process a message for a specific key the state will be null. Thus your application should handle the `null` value.

Try the following example (my java is rusty, this is in scala. Ask me if you need help converting it):

```
env.fromElements(("key1", 2),("key2", 4), ("key1", 5))
  .keyBy(_._1)
  .map {
    new RichMapFunction[(String, Int), (String, Int)] {

      lazy val stateTypeInfo: TypeInformation[Int] = implicitly[TypeInformation[Int]]
      lazy val serializer: TypeSerializer[Int] = stateTypeInfo.createSerializer(getRuntimeContext.getExecutionConfig)
      lazy val stateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor[Int]("dummy state", serializer)

      var testVar: ValueState[Int] = _

      override def open(config: Configuration) = {
        testVar = this.getRuntimeContext.getState(stateDescriptor)
      }

      override def map(in: (String, Int)): (String, Int) = {
        println(s"message $in")
        println(s"state ${testVar.value()}")
        println()
        val sum = Option(testVar.value()).getOrElse(0) + in._2
        testVar.update(sum)
        (in._1, sum)
      }
  }
}.print()

env.execute()
```

This should produce:

```
message (key1,2) (first time key1 is seen)
state null       (state is null)

(key1,2)  (output)
message (key2,4) (first time key2 is seen)
state null       (state is null)

(key2,4)  (output)
message (key1,5) (second time key1 is seen!! We stored something there!)
state 2 (we stored a 2)

(key1,7) (thus output is 2+5=7)
```

Comment: test is not supposed to be null test.value() supposed to be null. And the problem is that open is not being called otherwise the println would show.

Comment: Did you try to @override the open function?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I could solve the problem by replacing the following import:

```
import java.lang.module.Configuration;
```

with this one:

```
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
```